# LogLinear and LogLog plots in android

Tags: android, logarithm, graphing

I want my application to be able to display [frequency response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response) graphs but I cannot find any graphing library that has this functionality. I am currently using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)  for some other charts (and it is great !) but sadly I could not find any way to use it to do log plots. I have also tried using numAndroidCharts ([numcharts logplot example](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-logarithmic-line-chart-using-numandroidcharts-library-tutorial/)), but that library seems broken/outdated since i couldn't even get the example code to work properly. Is there anyway that you know of to achieve this ?

Comment: You can use `MPAndroidChart` with log scales, you need to convert your values with `Math.log10(value)`, set this converted value to your `Entry` and label the scale with your desired values. (I have done it this way) Have you tried this already?

Comment: Hi Amylinn, no i have not tried that. So if i want a logarithmic x axis, and i want to add a value (x,y), for the entry I add the point (log10(x),y), but what do you mean with the labeling the scale with the desired values ?

Comment: For example if your value is `1E-5`, `Math.log10(value) = -5`, `-5` will be your label. So you need an `AxisFormatter` where you convert your value back to the log scale, for example `String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2E", Math.pow(10,value));` I'll add an answer.

Comment: I will try that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `MPAndroidChart` with a log scale with converted values.

For example if your value is `1E-5`:

```
value = 1E-5;
Entry entry = new Entry();
entry.setX(Math.log10(value)); // entry.getX() will return -5
```

Because your value now is `-5` you need to create an `AxisFormatter` to show that it really represents an logarithmic value:

```
public class Log10AxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2E", Math.pow(10,value));
    }
}
```

You need to set an instance of this to your axis when you create your chart:

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new Log10AxisValueFormatter());
```